# Getting one puppet class applied regardless of other class failures

Tags: puppet

**Given**

*manifest/site.pp*

```
...
include foo::bar
include baz::alpha
include baz::beta
include baz::gamma
...
```

Where

- `foo::bar` creates `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/config_file.yaml`
- `foo::alpha` through `foo::gamma` are custom types which use `puppet_x` classes that require the above file to operate, and will throw `Puppet::Error` if the file is not available.
- `baz::alpha` through `baz::gamma` are classes which use custom types``` foo:beta`` through ```foo:gamma``` to define resources.

**Question**

How do I ensure that `foo::bar` executes to completion regardless of the failure of any of the `baz` classes?

I'm open to any suggestion on how to achieve this.  A preferred solution would be one that doesn't require a mass rewrite for the `foo` custom types, but if that's the only way, I'll do it.

**Things Tried**

- Using `Class['foo::bar'] -> Class[...] -> ...` (dash arrow) to ensure order of application.
- Using `Class['foo::bar'] ~> Class[...] -> ...` (tilde arrow) to ensure order of application.
- Adding `autorequire(:file)` to all of the `foo::alpha` through `foo::gamma` custom types.
- Leaving no relationship between `foo::bar` and any other class.
- Trying to `catch Puppet:error do err(message) end` in all the `foo` custom type providers.

**The Actual Problem**

I had not realized that Puppet would attempt to instantiate all of the classes before applying the changes that any of them were supposed to perform.  Even when a 'stage' is used, all classes are initialized before anything is done.

What was really going on was that one of the Custom Types was attempting to use a Ruby utility class that depended upon the configuration file that would have been created by the `foo::bar` class in it's own 'initialize' method.

This utility class would catastrophically fail when the configuration file was not present.  Which would cascade back to Puppet and cause it to fail the entire run.

Comment: Only a suggestion since you haven't posted the full manifest definitions - I've found very useful the `before`, `after`, `require`, `notify` options - https://puppet.com/blog/class-containment-puppet

Comment: Before and Notify are functionally equivalent to the dash arrow and tilde arrow.  (I think I've got those the right way around.)  In any case, I found the real source of the problem, and will post an answer as soon as I confirm that the fix works.

Comment: I mention before and after namely because they aren't. I know they are supposed to be but I've had issues not once. Ive always hated puppet for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note: I'm still learning Puppet, so apply these suggestions with care.***

It isn't actually possible to force a class to run ***entirely*** before absolutely everything else you're trying to do.  Puppet will *always* initialize all the classes you use before it attempts to apply *any* of them.  Even if you use a 'stage' to try and force the issue.

In retrospect, this should have been obvious.  Puppet cannot call the 'autorequire', 'autobefore', 'autoafter', or 'autonotify' methods if it hasn't already initialized the custom type instances, so it cannot complete the ordering until it does.

However, for those of you who are running into problems, here are the various solutions that will work to ensure that a given class is at least *applied* before other classes.

**Simple Ordering**

*manifest/site.pp*

```
node default {
...
include foo::bar
include baz::alpha
include baz::beta
include baz::gamma

Class['foo::bar']
-> Class['baz::alpha']
-> Class['baz::beta']
-> Class['baz::gamma']
...
}
```

This will apply the classes in the order shown, from 'foo::bar' to 'baz::gamma' unless something else interferes.  There are other operators available, see [Language: Relationships](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_relationships.html#operands).

While the operators are functionally *close* to the class relationships 'before', 'after', 'subscribe', 'notify', there are reportedly differences that can occasionally trip you up.

Still, if you've written your classes for reuse, with different orderings needed for different setups, this is still your best bet.  The same technique works in 'role' classes if you're using the 'profile/role' design pattern.

**Stages**

Under special circumstances, which I have yet to run into, it may be necessary to ensure that certain classes are run before/after everything in the 'main' stage, or any other stage.  There are some problems with using this method, see [Language: Run stages](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_run_stages.html).

The basic idea is that you can declare your own stages, and relate them to each other using the 'simple' techniques above.  Then you can assign classes to stages.  Each stage will run in the order you specify, and the classes within that stage will run in either their natural order, or whatever order you've specified.

The problem is that you have to use 'resource-like' specifications for the classes, rather than using "include".  That means you can only specify the class once.  If you try to specify it twice, it will trigger an error from Puppet.

*module/somewhere/manifest/something.pp*

```
class somewhere::something {
  ...
  include baz::alpha
  include baz::beta
  include baz::gamma

  stage { 'beforemain':
    before => Stage['main'],
  }

  class { 'foo::bar':
    stage => beforemain,
  }

  Class['baz::alpha']
  -> Class['baz::beta']
  -> Class['baz::gama']
}
```

Class 'foo::bar' will be *applied* before all the 'baz' classes because it runs in the 'beforemain' stage, and by default, the 'baz' classes run in the 'main' stage.

The above will work, but if you add the following:

*module/elsewhere/manifest/elsewhen.pp*

```
class elsewhere::elsewhen {
  ...
  include foo::bar
  ...
 }
```

and apply the 'elsewhere::elsewhen' class in the same catalog as 'somewhere::something', you're going to get an error from Puppet.